# Handling warning in dynamo python

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I’m getting this warning window while convert .sat to .rfa. How can I handle this warning automatically using dynamo python.
I have also referred IFailurePreprocessor, but couldn’t use it before the warning message doesn’t falls under that category. And checked other failure messages as but couldn’t find one.
can anyone help me

[image]with this?

I have also tried dialog box event based on  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936752/how-to-automatically-handle-dialogboxshowing-event-in-pythonrevit-dynamo)

Comment: what is the full info when you "Expand>>"?